# Private or Protected Set for a MustOverride Property

Tags: vb.net, properties, abstract

I'd like to have a Private or Protected "Setter" for a property that also happens to be an abstract (MustOverride). I'm porting some code from C# to VB and in C# this is pretty straight forward. In VB not so much (for me anyway).

Some code...

In C#...

```
public abstract class BaseClassWithAnAbstractProperty
{
    public abstract int AnAbstractIntegerProperty { get; protected set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseClassWithAnAbstractProperty
{
    private int _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField = 0;

    public override int AnAbstractIntegerProperty 
    {
        get { return _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField; }
        protected set { _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField = value; }
    }
}
```

In VB...

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClassWithAnAbstractProperty

    Public MustOverride Property AnAbstractIntegerProperty() As Integer

End Class

Public Class Foo
    Inherits BaseClassWithAnAbstractProperty

    Private _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField As Integer


    Public Overrides Property AnAbstractIntegerProperty As Integer
        Get
            Return _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField 
        End Get
        Protected Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _anAbstractIntegerPropertyField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The issue seems to be the inability to flesh-out the Get/Set specifics in the declaration.

Am I chasing a ghost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protected Set in VB.Net for a property defined in an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362381/protected-set-in-vb-net-for-a-property-defined-in-an-interface)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The question is different. It happens that the answer works for both questions.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, the closest VB translation would give you:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClassWithAnAbstractProperty

    Public ReadOnly MustOverride Property AnAbstractIntegerProperty() As Integer

End Class
```

This *might* work, but [as I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362381/protected-set-in-vb-net-for-a-property-defined-in-an-interface), VB doesn't support this for Interfaces, at least

Comment: Yeah I just copy/pasted one of your comments actually. I'm going for the work around. Thanks